# server listens on 127.0.0.1, do I need firewall?

Tags: security, networking, localhost, firewall

I run a "private" service on my computer, which I do not want to be accessible from other computers. I configured it to only listen on `127.0.0.1`. Do I still need a restrictive firewall? 
For example, is it possible to receive a packet on `eth1`, which would somehow have `127.0.0.1` as its destination address? Then, if my FORWARD chain is permissive, wouldn't it get delivered to my server listening on the localhost?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`127.0.0.1` is only for local computer "loopback". They are [required to be dropped](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loopback#Martian_packets) if they come from outside the local computer. So no firewall is required if the app is only listening on `127.0.0.1`.

Comment: What if I explicitly add something like `-i eth0 ... -j DNAT --to-destination 127.0.0.1:80` to the `PREROUTING` ? They still will not pass?

Comment: I'm not an IP mapping expert but I believe that you are asking what happens if you route external packets to `127.0.0.1`. If you can do that I think that `PREROUTING` happens early enough in the process that it will appear to your service as if it came from the localhost. You should be able to quickly test this though. Doing this seems antithetical to keeping your service private.

Comment: Thank you. I think you are right. But I am insufficiently convinced to accept your answer. I wish somebody explained to me precisely what mechanism is responsible for dropping those "Martian" packages, and to what extent it depends on the firewall properly configured.

Comment: I found more information here: http://superuser.com/questions/661772/iptables-redirect-to-localhost and here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25668858/iptables-regarding-local-address which basically confirms what Neil wrote. So, I am closing the question.